# Anyone running Postgresql in production with NAMEDATALEN increased to 128 or more?

Tags: postgresql

I've recompiled postgres with the modifications from this patch: https://gist.github.com/langner/5c7bc1d74a8b957cab26, most important modification being `#define NAMEDATALEN 256`.

Server is up and running, basic queries seem to work.

My concern is: can this patch cause stability or performance issues in the long run with heavy production use?

Side note: I am implementing some data driven computing micro-language on top of postgres. To keep things simple I prefer to "compile" my micro-language directly into postgres tables/views/triggers. I don't want to maintain my own metadata tables since postgres provides everything I need except that the default NAMEDATALEN of 64 chars is a bit too low for my needs.

Comment: No, that should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.